# PHP Combinar datos de varios arrays

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente caso, que no logro hacer que funcione.
Sólo funciona con un dato por cada variable.
Entiendo que debo asociar las variables, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias!

```html
<?php

$TotalValores=700;
$Saldo=array(100,300,200);
$Comprobantes=array(5548,5549,5550); 
$MontoAPagar=array(80,300,200);

$CantComprobantes=count($Comprobantes);


echo 'Total de Dinero: '.$TotalValores.'<br><br>';
 
for ($row = 0; $row < $CantComprobantes; $row++)
{

echo 'Saldo de factura: '.$Saldo.'<br>';

 if ($MontoAPagar >= $Saldo){
     $SaldoDeFactura = $Saldo - $MontoAPagar;
  $TotalValores = $TotalValores - $MontoAPagar;
      
     echo 'Monto pagado: '.$MontoAPagar.'<br>';
     echo 'Saldo despues del pago: '.$SaldoDeFactura.' <br>';
     echo 'Factura PAGADA.<br>';
     echo 'Valores restante: '.$TotalValores.'<br>';
}else{
    $SaldoDeFactura = $Saldo - $MontoAPagar;
 $Pagado = $MontoAPagar - $SaldoDeFactura;
    $TotalValores = $TotalValores - $MontoAPagar;

    echo 'Monto pagado: '.$MontoAPagar.'<br>'; 
    echo 'Saldo despues del pago: '.$SaldoDeFactura.' <br>';
    echo 'Factura IMPAGA<br>'; 
    echo 'Dinero restante: '.$TotalValores.'<br>';  
    
}  
}

?>
```

Esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el código como lo tienes, estando seguro de que `$Saldo`, `$Comprobantes` y `$MontoAPagar` siempre contienen el mismo número de elementos, debes especificar con qué elemento estás trabajando dentro del bucle, poniendo `$row` entre corchetes:

```
echo 'Saldo de factura: ' . $Saldo[$row] . '<br>';
```

Y lo mismo para `$Comprobantes` y `$MontoAPagar`.

Una vez dicho esto, yo cambiaría el código para que la función de donde saques estos datos te devuelva una estructura así:

```
$datos = array(
    'TotalValores' => 700,
    'Facturas' => array (
        array (
            'Saldo' => 100,
            'Comprobante' => 5548,
            'MontoAPagar' => 80,
        ),
        // dos arrays más para las otras dos facturas
    )
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! tu respuesta me ha resuelto mi problema.